# Увеличение высоты div вверх при ховере

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть набор карточек, которые находятся во флекс-контейнере и по наведению курсора на любую из карточек, она должна увеличиться в высоте вверх чтобы в заголовке карточки появилось место для текста (на картинке цифра 6). Проблема в том, что у карточек динамичные размеры и расположение в зависимости от содержимого (квадратики).
[image: скриншот]

На скриншоте показано как реализовано сейчас, при наведении на пятую карточку, у нее появляется дополнительный блок с текстом "6" и она расширяется вниз. Не могу добиться нужного поведения с абсолютным позиционированием.

```
const container = styled('div', {
  display: 'flex',
  gap: '4px',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  marginTop: '20px',
});

const card = styled('div', {
  display: 'flex',
  padding: '8px',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  gap: '4px',
  border: '1px solid $grey50',
  borderRadius: '8px',
  height: 'fit-content',
  transition: '0.2s',

  '&:hover': {
    borderColor: '$grey100',
  },
});

const row = styled('div', {
  display: 'flex',
  gap: '2px',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
});

const block = styled('div', {
  width: '16px',
  height: '16px',
  borderRadius: '2px',
  backgroundColor: '$grey75',
});
```

Comment: добавьте исходный код Вашей программы, трудно гадать на кофейной гуще

Comment: А что за `styled`? Это созданная вами функция, библиотека, фреймворк...?

Comment: библиотека stitches, надстройка над css

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант на голом `CSS` где мы ставим максимальную высоту элемента в 0 и при наведении увеличиваем блок до максимально возможной высоты элемент которая может быть.

```js
const cardItemsVariants = ['green', 'gray', 'yellow', 'red']

const columns = 8
const cardItems = 3 * 6 

const items = [...new Array(columns)].map(() => (
  [...new Array(cardItems)].map(() => (
    cardItemsVariants[Math.floor(Math.random()*cardItemsVariants.length)]
  ))
))

const containerElem = document.querySelector('.container')

for (const [index, cardItems] of items.entries()) {
  const cardElem = document.createElement('div')
  cardElem.classList.add('card')

  const textWrapperElem = document.createElement('div')
  textWrapperElem.classList.add('text')
  const textElem = document.createElement('p')
  textElem.innerText = `${index} Lorem ipsum...`
  textWrapperElem.appendChild(textElem)
  cardElem.appendChild(textWrapperElem)
  
  const cardItemsElem = document.createElement('div')
  cardItemsElem.classList.add('items')

  for (const cardItem of cardItems) {
    const cardItemElem = document.createElement('div')
    cardItemElem.classList.add('item', cardItem)
    cardItemsElem.appendChild(cardItemElem)
  }
  
  cardElem.appendChild(cardItemsElem)
  
  containerElem.appendChild(cardElem)
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: start;
}

.card {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 4px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.green { background-color: #afe0bb; }
.gray { background-color: #e1e1e6; }
.yellow { background-color: #ffd57d; }
.red { background-color: #ffc4b0; }

.text {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.card:hover .text {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Так как код вы не предоставили, мне пришлось накинуть рандомную генерацию блоков чтобы воспроизвести пример вашей картинки, его не нужно брать во внимание, он просто для демонстрации

Более подробные варианты растягивания высоты уже были заданы в этом вопросе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css

Comment: Есть вариант на JS в котором мы можем получить реальное значение высоты скрытого заранее элемента и растянуть его, чтобы сделать более универсальное и правильное решение, если нужно то могу добавить его в ответ

Comment: но в вашем коде блоки едут вниз, а нужно чтобы низ был зафиксирован, а расширялся вверх